# If $P$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ , then does there exist a minimal closed set $S$ s.t. $P(S)=1$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal B$ be the borel sigma algebra algebra on $\mathbb R$ , let $P$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ , then is it true that the partially ordered set (w.r.t. set inclusion )

$\mathcal A:=\{S$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R : P(S)=1 \}$ has a minimal element ? It is trivial to see $\mathcal A$ is nonempty as $\mathbb R \in \mathcal A$ , to apply Zorn's Lemma the only place I am stuck at is the lower bound of any chain , say $\{S_{\lambda} \}$ is a chain in $\mathcal A$ , then obviously $\cap S_{\lambda}$ is a closed set , but how can I show that $P(\cap S_{\lambda})=1$ ? Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be the union of all the open sets $U\subset\Bbb R$ such that $P(U)=0$. Then $G$ is open and (exercise!) $P(G)=0$. The set $S:=\Bbb R\setminus G$ is closed and  $P(S) =1$. If $F$ is any other closed subset of $\Bbb R$ with $P(F)=1$, then $F^c$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$ with $P(F^c)=0$; therefore $F^c\subset G$, and so $S\subset F$. [This $S$ is called the *support* of $P$.]

Comment: if $P(G)=0$ is exercise then what improvement have you done other than restating the problem .... ?

Comment: Sometimes the key to a problem is looking at it in the right way. As to the exercise: Let $\mathcal G$ be the class of open sets with $P$ measure $0$. Then (because $\Bbb R$ is second countable) there is a sequence $(G_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of elements of $\mathcal G$ such that $G=\cup_{n=1}^\infty G_n$. Then $P(G)=P(\cup_nG_n)\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(G_n)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known fact that for every non-empty subset $\mathcal{A}$ of a $\sigma$-algebra, there is a infimum $S'$. Further, if $\mathcal{A}$ is direted down-wards, there exists a sequence $\{S_n\}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $S_n \searrow S'$.

In your case, it is not difficult to see that $\mathcal{A}$ is fact direted down-wards. Then, let us take  a sequence $\{S_n\}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $S_n \searrow S'$, where $S'$ is the infimum.

We have that $S_n$ has probability $1$, we obtain that $S'=\bigcap S_n$ has probability $1$ too.